# Pinterest Board widget search

Tags: pinterest

I'd like to display a board with a search parameter provided by my back-end.

According to the docs example:

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/anapinskywalker/style/"
   data-pin-do="embedBoard"
   data-pin-board-width="400"
   data-pin-scale-height="320"
   data-pin-scale-width="100">
</a>
```

displays that user's board.

I've tried with:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedBoard" 
   data-pin-board-width="980" 
   data-pin-scale-height="720" 
   data-pin-scale-width="220" 
   href="https://www.pinterest.com/search/?q=test"></a>
```

but got no return, I've looked the browser's network tab and I didn't find a request or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To display an embedded Pinterest board you’ll need the HTML and also the Pinterest JS, e.g.:

```
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I’m uncertain about the search functionality. 
More info:
[Pinterest Widget Docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/)